# 'no routes matched location' in React Router Error

Tags: reactjs, router

Im trying to link my product page to my shop page via a button using React Router. When I click the button and inspect my product page it shows a error message of 'no routes matched location'. At the moment the only things that appear on the page are the header and footer which are located in my app. Below is my shop page with the said button. Thanks for your help.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AddToCart from './Components/AddToCart';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate } from "react- 
router-dom";
import Product from './Product';

const HOME_GARDEN = 'home and garden';
const ART = 'Art';
const ACCESSORIES = 'Accessories';
const DIGITAL_PHOTOGRAPHS = 'Digital Photographs';
const FASHION = 'Fashion';
const FOOTWEAR = 'Footwear';
const JEWELLERY = 'Jewellery';
 const ALL = 'All';

export default function Shop({ setCart, cart, handleClick }) {
const [products] = useState([
{
    category: ART,
    name: 'Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork',
    cost: 200,
    image:'images/bowiebig.jpeg',
    image2: 'images/bowiesmall.jpeg',
    image3:'images/bowie2small.jpeg',
    description: "Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork floral 
 painting on wooden canvas with an original pop art style David Bowie Mugshot on top 
 painting is framed with a red baroque style frame including the words deadly flowers 
 bloom around frame",

  },

  {
      category: ACCESSORIES,
      name: 'F&F Ladies Long Black Real Leather Size Small Gloves',
      cost: 35,
      image:'images/Fred.jpeg',
      image2: '',
      image3:'',
      description: 'F&F Ladies Long Black Real Leather Size Small Gloves with ruched 
    horizontal detailing on the front. Gloves are in good condition ',

    },
    {
        category: DIGITAL_PHOTOGRAPHS,
        name: 'Black on Black Original Limited Edition Digital Photograph',
        cost: 50,
        image:'images/BlackonBlack.jpg',
        image2: '',
        image3:'',
        description: 'Upon purchase you will receive links to download the digital 
   photograph in the thank you page of the checkout as well as an emailed link that 
     will last 30 days. ',

      },
      {
          category: FASHION,
          name: 'Ladies Small BOY London Distressed Acid Wash Blue Midi Denim Skirt',
          cost: 50,
          image:'images/Boy.jpeg',
          image2: '',
          image3:'',
          description: 'Ladies Small BOY London Distressed Acid Wash Blue Midi Denim 
     Skirt. BOY London sizes run small. This skirt is size 8/10 even though the label 
      says large. Condition is New with tags.',

        },
        {
            category: FOOTWEAR,
            name: 'Ladies Size 8 / 41 Black Real Suede Jeffrey Campbell Platform Open 
      Toe Sandals',
            cost: 60,
            image:'images/Campbell.jpeg',
            image2: '',
            image3:'',
            description: 'Ladies UK Size 8 European size 41 black real suede Jeffrey 
    Campbell high platform open-toe sandals with adjustable strap. The sandals are in 
   good condition as theyve only worn outside a few times. The heel and platform is 
     made from wood so the sandals are sturdy but relatively lightweight. ',

          },
          {
              category: JEWELLERY,
              name: 'Jean Paul Gaultier Scandal Bottle Top Customised Fishnet 
    Necklace',
              cost: 50,
              image:'images/Scandal.jpeg',
              image2: '',
              image3:'',
              description: 'Jean Paul Gaultier Scandal Bottle Top Customised Necklace 
     made with braided fishnets.',

            },


{
    category: HOME_GARDEN,
    name: 'Blanket',
    cost: 19.99,
    image:
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
   q=tbn%3AANd9GcSpwdYDmUL_ZEqhLV7ZWRdQAU7DGcGaxtCt7SrTlL
    9umrQs2Un7rj9Nbb9Vq01RtEfA0eAVmdt-&usqp=CAc',
    page:'Blanket',
},
]);


const navigate = useNavigate()

const [category, setCategory] = useState(ALL);



  const getProductsInCategory = () => {
  if (category === ALL) {
    return products;
  } else {
    return products.filter((product) => product.category === category);
  }
 };


return (
<>
  <h1>Shop</h1>

    <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ART)}>
      Art</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(HOME_GARDEN)}>
        Home and Garden</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ACCESSORIES)}>
      Accessories</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(DIGITAL_PHOTOGRAPHS)}>
      Digital Photographs</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(FASHION)}>
      Fashion</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(FOOTWEAR)}>
      Footwear</button>
    <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(JEWELLERY)}> Jewellery</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ALL)}>
          All</button>

  <div className="products">
      {getProductsInCategory().map((product, idx) =>(
        <div className="product" key={idx}>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h4>£{product.cost}</h4>
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          <br />


            <button onClick={() => navigate('/product')}>
                View Product
              </button>
          <AddToCart product={product} cart={cart} setCart=. 
    {setCart}/>

         
        </div>
    ))}
 </div>

</>
);
}
```

my app looks like this

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 
 "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Shop from './Shop';
import Homepage from './Homepage';
import Accessories from './Accessories';
import About from './About';
import ContactUs from './ContactUs';
import Product from './Product';
import Blog from './Blog';
import Cart from './Cart';



 function App() {

 const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);


const getCartTotal = () => {
return cart.reduce(
  (sum, { quantity }) => sum + quantity,
  0
);
};
return (

<Router>
  <nav>
  <img src="images/Logo2.jpeg" alt="my logo" className="rounded" 
 width="160px"/>
    <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
    <Link to="/Shop"> Shop </Link>
    <Link to="/Blog"> Blog </Link>
    <Link to="/About"> About </Link>
    <Link to="/ContactUs"> Contact Us </Link>
    <Link to="/Shop"><button type="button">Shop</button></Link>
    <Link to="/Cart"><button type="button">Go To 
 Cart({getCartTotal()})</button></Link>


  </nav>
  <Routes>

    <Route path="/Shop" element={<Shop />} />
    <Route path="/Blog" element={<Blog />} />
    <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/ContactUs" element={<ContactUs />} />
    <Route path="/Cart" element={<Cart />} />
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage />} />


      </Routes>


  <nav>
  <h4>Purchasing Info</h4>
    <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
    <Link to="/Shop"> Shop </Link>
    <h4>Contact &amp; Questions</h4>
    <Link to="/Blog"> Blog </Link>
    <Link to="/About"> About </Link>
      <h4>Social</h4>
    <Link to="/ContactUs"> Contact Us </Link>



  </nav>
  </Router>

);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is your router config? There isn't a BrowserRouter component with its children defined, then of course /product won't be a matched route

Comment: Try `navigate(`/students/view/${rowData.uid}`, { replace: true });`. , If it not worked, then you may have problem in router definitions,

Comment: Ive got the router in my app but I havent used browser router. How would I do that? thanks

Comment: You don't seem to have a `/product` route defined anywhere... makes sense that no route would match when you navigate there

Comment: hi Mike, Ive tried to put a /product route in with my others in my app and when I click on the button theres just a blank page -  no footer or header.